# Induction Problem ($n^2 ≤ 2^n$)

Tags: computer-science, induction

So I have this induction problem:

> $$n^2 ≤ 2^n \;\text{ for } \; n ≥ 4$$

I know the base case is ($n=4$) which checks out.

I know the hyp is ($n=k$) giving $k^2 ≤ 2^k$.

However, I am getting stuck on the actual proof part (i.e. $n = k+1$).

I know $2^{k+1}$ can be broken apart into $2\times 2^k$ but I haven't seen where that can help.

Edits:

Expanding out the $(k+1)^2$, I get $k^2 + 2k + 1 ≤ 2^{k+1}$
Using the hyp I can do $2^k + 2k +1 ≤ (2)(2k)$

Comment: What happens when you expand $(k+1)^2$ and use that $k^2 \le 2^k$?

Comment: Tenplicate.${{}}$

Comment: @grantfgates Updated with your comments. Still a bit lost.

Comment: By using condition that $k\ge4$, we know that $k^2\ge4k$, and $2k\ge2\cdot4>1$.